# apache wrong HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME in .htaccess but correct in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server-name, http-host

I have an apache web server, version: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat), on it I have multiple virtual hosts

now, in .htaccess, I have a redirect to cut the trailing slashes, but there, the variables HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME are **always** loaded with default (first) virtual host, and not with the current virtual host

and the problem to be even strange, in php those variables are loaded correctly

**any idea what to do ?** I spent few hours digging google with no result :(

LE seems like is not clear enough, let's just say that I have only 2 virtual hosts: [www.ex.com](http://www.ex.com) and mail.ex.com, and first is also the default virtual host when I type httpd -S ... now, when I access mail.ex.com, in .htaccess HTTP_HOST is loaded with [www.ex.com](http://www.ex.com) and not mail.ex.com

Comment: _“any idea what to do ?”_ - giving us a _proper_ problem description, would be a start … Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Have you enabled the virtual host? I can't comment on Red Hat but with Ubuntu you need to a2ensite virtualhostname to enable the host.

Comment: "any idea what to do ?” - giving us a proper problem description, would be a start … Please go read How to Ask and minimal reproducible example. – CBroe", can you please tell me what is not clear ? I have wrong value for http_host and server_name but only in .htaccess, what else I need to explain ?

Comment: "Have you enabled the virtual host? I can't comment on Red Hat but with Ubuntu you need to a2ensite virtualhostname to enable the host. – user1020496 7 mins ago" virtual hosts are working properly, and I have several ...

Comment: You say they are _both_ "loaded with default (first) virtual host" - what exactly do you mean by that? Are they both set to the value of the `ServerName` directive? The problem with that is that the `HTTP_HOST` server variable has nothing to do with the `ServerName` as defined in _any_ vHost. It is _always_ set to the value of the `Host` header on the HTTP request (hence its name). (Which could be affected if you are behind a front-end proxy?) Are you sure the other vHosts are even being triggered?

Comment: I think is obvious, i have for exampe www.example.com as first and default virtual host, but when I try to access mail.example.com then in .htaccess HTTP_HOST is loaded still with www.example.com instead of mail.example.com

Comment: "I think is obvious" - No, it's not "obvious". Particularly since what you appear to be describing is "impossible". As I stated above, the `HTTP_HOST` is never changed to "match the virtual host" (by which I assume you mean the value of the `ServerName` directive (or `ServerAlias`?)). Assuming you do have a `ServerName` directive defined and are not allowing the server to calculate this? `SERVER_NAME` on the other hand will change to match the value of the `ServerName`, only if `UseCanonicalHost On` is set. However, only one vHost can be processed/matched - so again, this does not make sense.

Comment: This is presumably your own server, with no hosting control panel installed (like cPanel)? Please post your server config (including vHost containers).